# unique serial no of child record under each parent record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

suppose I have models

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

I have an attribute for child call it serial_no. I want to add a validation so that every children has a unique serial no under a parent how can I add this validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use scoped  validation:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  validates :serial_no, :uniqueness => {:scope => :parent_id}
end
```